# dot product of surface and gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, inner-products

I've been asked to answer if the following dot product make sense: $F \cdot \nabla f$, when $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3)$. Following the solutions the answer is yes. It has been a while since my linear algebra class. What are the requirements for dot products? Only the length of the vectors? So we ignore further information like if it is a row or column vector? Furthermore, can we treat a gradient just as a normal row vector?

Comment: There is a typo in your text: you define twice $f$. One of them should be $F$.

Comment: In the usual way that vector calculus is taught, no distinction is made between row vectors and column vectors, so dot-products are defined so long as the two vectors have the same length. Where such a distinction is made, $\nabla f$ is typically defined to be a column-vector (whereas its transpose $(\nabla f)^T$ can be seen as the true "derivative" $df$ of $f$). The dot-product is defined for two column-vectors of the same length.